# How to allow a-z 0-9 and a dash in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a CMS and want to create a nice slug in the search engine

I've tried to achieve it with a regex, but it looks like it is ignoring to totally

A little example:

```
$('#name_nl').blur(function() {
        var string = $('#name_nl').val();
        string = string.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9-]/g,'');
        $('#slug_nl').val(string.toLowerCase());
        //console.log("Blurred name_nl");
    });
```

In the above example it should give the output where I allow a first character to be A-Z a-z and 0-9 and after that the - is also allowed.

But when I test it on `(WI-FI) network` i get `(wi-fi) network`

I already tested it on a regex tester, it looks great
But Javascript does not like it...

https://regex101.com/r/ev3uFR/2

How can I remove every special character, instead of the - and remove them as first and last character?

Comment: Try [`replace(/^-+|-+$|[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/ev3uFR/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are genius. How easy can it be :)
Maybe you can add it as a answer, so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest removing hyphens at the start and end of the string, and remove all chars other than alphanumeric and `-` in any other contexts:

```
.replace(/^-+|-+$|[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/g, "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ev3uFR/3).

**Details**

- `^-+` - start of string position and 1 or more `-` chars there
- `|`  -or
- `-+$` - 1 or more hyphens at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `[^A-Za-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, digits or/and `-` chars.

JS demo:

```js
console.log("a(WI-FI) netwerken".replace(/^-+|-+$|[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/g, ""));
console.log("--a(WI-FI) netwerken".replace(/^-+|-+$|[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/g, ""));
console.log("a(WI-FI) netwerken--".replace(/^-+|-+$|[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/g, ""));
```